# Hamiltonian for the time-like particle on the geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics

I am trying to reproduce the results from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08293) paper. On page 2 of the paper, they have an equation: $$2 H=-\frac{\dot{r}^2}{g(r)}-L \dot{\phi }+E \dot{t}=\epsilon\tag{9}$$
where they make a comment that $\epsilon=1$ for the time-like particle on the geodesic and $\epsilon=0$ for the light-like particle.

I am unable to comprehend the fact that how the Hamiltonian can be 0 or 1 for the given particles.
Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hamiltonian here the dot in $\dot t$ etc. refers to the derivative with respect to the affine parameter. So the Hamiltonian represents a sort of conserved quantity with respect to the affine parameter. This conserved quantity turns out to be the norm of the tangent vector to the worldline.

For a timelike worldline the norm of the tangent vector is always 1. This is the source of the famous idea that is often taught in pop-sci sources where they describe all objects going through spacetime at c. It is not really a deep statement, just that the affine parameter makes the tangent vector a unit vector and in relativity the unit of speed is c.

For a lightlike worldline the norm of the tangent vector is, by definition, 0. Hence $\epsilon = 0$ indicates a null geodesic and $\epsilon = 1$ indicates a timelike geodesic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit on the norm of the tangent vector part? Why is it always 1 for the timelike worldline? Any references would be truly helpful.

Comment: @codebpr here is a link where I learned about this issue, but regarding a Lagrangian instead of a Hamiltonian: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/conserved-quantity-along-affine-parameter.1017000/ I will update the answer itself with a little on the norm of the tangent vector

Comment: Thanks a lot for the much needed help!